# Drawing and inserting mathematical symbols on a Dia generated graph

Tags: graphics

I use graph via Dia  to draw  graphs.  But I want to insert an equation or symbol on the graph. Is there any way to put an equation symbol such as `$\alpha$` or `$\beta$` on the graph?

I have inserted latex into the dia directly, and it is showing like this: [image]

EDIT:[image]

Comment: In Dia or in the generated TikZ code? Please provide an MWE.

Comment: It's not clear whether you export the Dia figure as a picture, or you export it as TikZ code and embed this code in your document. Please provide a complete minimal working example of how you intend to import the graph to your document.

Comment: I was trying to draw in the dia without code but when I finished the drawing I wanted to insert  various math symbol. But there was nothing in DIa to be added. How can I convert the image to TikZ code?

Comment: You can add equations or symbols 
or other drawing on top of the `dia` picture: see e.g. 
[drawing-on-an-image](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz)

Comment: How to run these code? will I insert into latex file? 

I have inserted already but the file is not showing i mean the editor is not working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Final

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset{algebraic,plotpoints=100,labelsep=3pt}

\def\f[#1,#2]{2*2^(-2.5*(#1-#2)^2)}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[showgrid=false](-3,0)(3.5,3)
    \psaxes[axesstyle=frame,tickstyle=bottom,ticks=x,ticksize=0 4pt,xsubticks=5,xsubticksize=.5,labels=none](0,0)(-3,0)(3,3)
    \uput[d](-1,0){$\omega_{\text{nl}}$}
    \uput[d](1.5,0){$\omega_{\text{lin}}$}
    \uput[d](0,0){\tiny Frequency}
    \psline{<-}(0,2)(1,2)
    \psset{linecolor=gray}
    \psline[linestyle=dashed](0,0)(0,3) 
    \psplot[linecolor=red,linestyle=dashed]{-3}{1}{\f[x,-1]}
    \psplot[linecolor=red]{-.5}{3}{\f[x,1.5]}
    \pcline{<->}(*-1.5 {\f[x,-1]})(*-.5 {\f[x,-1]})\nbput{$r_{\text{nl}}$}
    \pcline{<->}(*1 {\f[x,1.5]})(*2 {\f[x,1.5]})\nbput{$r_{\text{lin}}$}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how did you get the coordinates? Have you got from DIA? how can I predit coordinates for  the other graph? Like I have edited in the  question.

Comment: Actually I want to draw the graph  identical  I have added in the edit. I used DIA but inserting symbol is hard I think. I saw you are using latex code. So I am confused how to art in a better way.

Comment: But what you have edited is not look identical with the pic I have posted.

Comment: YOu made it thanks, Now please give me some tips so I can draw more graphics by  latex.
My questions are: 

(1) I have inserted your code  in a lex file but the  file is not running in latex editor kile. Is anything wrong? 

(2) How will I  see the instantaneous output  for the input I will give? more precisely, how did you do draw this pic accurately  by latex code? 

(3) Will I draw this by using latex editor or terminal in Ubuntu.  or I can use this into DIA)
 By the way I am using in Ubuntu. 

And atlast thanks you did great.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the complete drawing in Dia, you can chose to export the picture as LaTeX PGF macros. You'll then have a `.tex` file, lets say `yourDiaDrawing.tex`, which you can include in your document by `\input{pathToFile/yourDiaDrawing.tex}`. If you have added your labels in Dia, find the `node`s containing your label texts in `yourDiaDrawing.tex`. When exporting to TikZ, Dia assumes that every special character you have inserted are supposed to be that way, and escapes the characters. So your `math` dollars will be escaped `\$`, your backslashes will be escaped `\\` and so on. Remove the backslash, and LaTeX does the rest.

You'll probably find `node`s in `yourDiaDrawing.tex` that'll look something like this

```
\node[anchor=west] at (13.00\du,8.00\du){\$ \\alpha \$};
```

Comment: Awesome. So `\node[anchor=west] at (13.00\du,8.00\du){\$ \\alpha \$};` should be changed to `\node[anchor=west] at (13.00\du,8.00\du){$ \alpha $};`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a patch to keep TeX formulae unescaped in PGF export. Hopefuly, it will be merged soon.

See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=778836 and https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dia/merge_requests/3

Comment: How do I apply this patch should I remove Dia and install it again cloning your git, configuring and make?

Comment: Could you provide installation instructions?

Comment: @VitorAbella The patch has been merged in February 2019. Just download & build the recent version of Dia (currently the master branch). See https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/dia/blob/master/BUILDING.md

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can input the respective Unicode characters:

In a text box in dia press Ctrl+Shift+U, release the U, then type the UTF-32 hex code for the characters you want. For example for \alpha this would be 3b1.

Answer (score 0):

In Dia,  export the figure into  "Latex PGF Macro".   So the file becomes xxx.tex

Modify the tex file and find something like:   if you have latex symbol in the figure "\&" such as:

> `{smooth \ensuremath{\blackslash}\&}`
> change it to
> `{smooth \ensuremath{\&}}`

In the head of latex document, add

> `\usepackage{tikz}`

In the document use :

```
\begin{figure*}
    \label{fig-flowchart}
     \centerline{
            \resizebox{6in}{!}{\input{newfig/flowchart.tex}}
    }
           \caption{ The general flowchart of similarity learning process for quality assurance. }
\end{figure*}
```

It works for me.

You can also use inkspace's  export to pdf_tex, however, you should have tex written in the inkspace A's box, otherwise, there's newline and font problem.